# How can I pass a list of databases to sp_MSforeachdb?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql

I have the following script that when run gives me a comma delimited list of database names.

```
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        declare @db_list NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @command varchar(1000)

        SELECT @COMMAND = 'SELECT DB_NAME()'

         SELECT @db_list  = STUFF((
                                    SELECT ', ' + name FROM sys.databases
                                    WHERE name like '__Order'
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), 
                                    TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')

         -- in case there are no DBs to show, then show no DB '***'
         select @db_list = COALESCE(@db_list,'***') 

         SELECT @db_list = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(@DB_LIST,',', ',''')))  


         select @db_list
```

this gives me the following result:

```
UKOrder,' ATOrder,' AUOrder
```

1) this is giving the wrong result set, I would like it to be

```
'UKOrder','ATOrder','AUOrder'
```

2) how can I pass @db_list to sp_MSforeachdb?

suppose I would like to run

> select db_name()

inside each database in @db_list

UKOrder

ATOrder

AUOrder

Comment: I think that is not possible, you have to create your own cursor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Also you shouldn't use this undocumented, unsupported, buggy procedure in situations where it seems to work, either. I have written a better replacement [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/).

In fact, the procedure I wrote does support a parameter `@database_list`, in the form `'db1, db2, db3'` (note no need to fuss with embedded single quotes at all), so adopting it for your needs - rather than reinventing the wheel - seems logical.

If you need help with syntax that builds a delimited string from a set for other purposes, please create a different question. If you really need to have each database name enclosed in its own quotes, the last string element in your `REPLACE` command should be `''','''` and you need to surround the end result with a single quote at beginning and end too.

Answer (score 1):

Here a example of a cursor thats receive a list of bases

```
create table #tmp (base sysname)

declare @lst varchar(200)
set @lst='''master'',''msdb'''

insert into #tmp exec ('select name from sys.databases where name in ('+@lst+') ')

declare @bd sysname
declare pap_log cursor read_only forward_only for 

select * from #tmp

open pap_log
fetch next from pap_log into @bd
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 

/*Something to do*/

fetch next from pap_log into @bd
end
close pap_log
deallocate pap_log
```

Comment: Please don't use `sysdatabases` - look at [the warning in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179900(v=sql.90).aspx) for every version from 2005 on...

Comment: @AaronBertrand ok